# Unable to connect to pg database in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg

I am unable to connect to pg database, I don't see any console message while I run the following route below

My pg version: ^8.8.0

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const client = new Pool()

app.get('/connection', (req, res) => {
   client.query('SELECT $1::text as message', ['Hello world!'], (err, res) => {
      console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].message) // Hello World!
      client.end()
   })
});
```

Comment: What database *do* you want to connect to? How did you attempt to specify its host/dbname/credentials?

Comment: Try adding [`client.on('error', console.error)`](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#events) and specifying a `connectionTimeoutMillis` when constructing the pool. (Also don't name your pool `client`, that's confusing)

Comment: @Bergi I have used db from heroku but there I am getting some no encryption message and I also have used local db setted up using docker

Comment: Remember the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): if you get errors, _show those errors_ =) And Bergi's question is super important to answer in your post (by showing code) because right now, your code doesn't connect to a database. It runs the code for opening a pool, but without any kind of code that first tells the pg library to even connect to a database so it can start querying (even the [super minimal docs](https://node-postgres.com/#getting-started) for `pg` show you needing a `client.connect()`, for example).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `pool.query()` does create a client and connect it, it's just the pool being misnamed to `client` that's confusing

Comment: @Bergi I ran that application without docker with db_host as "localhost" it worked fine, but in docker it is not working with no errors